# '<' unable to resolve function overload and Parameters mismatch in Class template, Visual Studio compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, queue

[image: Image file to show error]
The error pointed out was at the end just before the };
I don't even see any function overloading or any mismatching parameters.
This is simply a queue data structure that I was trying to implement. But unfortunately, I got these compiler errors. I am sharing the whole code so that easily one can help, since neither I have any function overloaded, not even the constructor nor I have used mismatched parameter. I guess image will help out to see the error.

```
template<class T>
class Queue {
private:
    T* box;
    int front;
    int rear;
    int number_Of_Elements;
    int capacity;
public:
    Queue(int cap = 0) {
        capacity = cap;
        front = rear = 0;
        number_Of_Elements = 0;
    }
    bool Empty() {
        return size == 0;
    }
    int next(int i) {
        return ((i + 1) % capacity);
    }
    int previous(int i) {
        return ((i + (capacity - 1)) % capacity);
    }
    int get_Number_Of_Elements() {
        return number_Of_Elements;
    }
    void double_Box() {
        T* temp = new T[capacity * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            temp[i] = box[i];
        }
        front = 0;
        rear = number_Of_Elements;
        delete[] box;
        box = temp;
    }
    const T& peek() {
        T a = box[front];
        front = next(front);
        return a;
    }
    void printQueue() {
        cout << "Front is at : " << front << endl;
        cout << "Rear is at : " << rear << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < number_Of_Elements; i++) {
            cout << "box[" << i << "]" << " : " << box[i] << endl;
        }
        cout << "------------------------" << endl;
    }
    void Enqueue(const T& data);
    const T& Dequeue();
    ~Queue() {
        delete[] box;
    }
// error is exactly here -> };
};
```

Comment: Please show the __full__ error message.

Comment: Your posted code has some omissions: what is `T`? (Should there be a `template` line a the top?) What is `size`? When I added some 'guesses' as to what those should be, you code compiles (in MSVC) without error or warning.

Comment: did you forget a ; or } somewhere else I had these problems too but they always were a syntax error somewhere above the error message of the compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, there were issues, like some of the variables were not even initialized but they were being used, and the memory calculation errors were there. Like a pointer pointing somewhere in memory that actually does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with `size`. You haven't declared it.

I think the compiler tries to use some global function called size instead but it fails.

After declaring the capacity member var, add

```
size_t size;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6Gn44W)